# Terminal automatically logs out when starting java

Tags: java

I just downloaded java onto my Macbook pro (mid 2012). When I click java to start, the terminal window opened but it seems to be automatically logged out. Could anyone help me out? What possibly cause this? I checked around on internet but no luck so far. I need Java to run Clojure.

Message on the terminal is below

```
Last login: Tue Jun  7 23:12:35 on ttys001
S-no-MBP:~ sssss$ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java ; exit;
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Comment: Why did you download java? If you are learning the language, you should read a book or follow online tutorials.

Comment: Have you tried reading the error messge and following the link it suggests? "See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details."

Comment: You should open a terminal, and then run java from there. Then the terminal won't close right away, and you can work on adding the correct args to do whatever it is you are trying to do with java.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, the link was no help, the terminal does not take any command line args as it exited :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys!
I did a couple thing. I changed my user as administer privilege and down load "Java for OS X 2015-001 https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

It sorted all out :):) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> java ; exit;

You're telling it to exit after running java. So it does. I suggest you familiarize yourself with the shell, not just java.

Comment: It happens when java starts, so I cannot do anything about it.  Do you have any ideas why this happens? it something to do with java. I use ide so I am familiar with shell x

Answer (score 1):

The `exit;` at the end of your first line is logging  you out of your terminal session. Here are the cojure install docs for is: https://gist.github.com/rakhmad/2407109

Comment: Exactly, I have no idea why it exits... However Xcode (a requirement for the link you mentioned) seems to be amazing :) I am downloading it now! Thanks. I still want to download java though

Answer (score 1):

Hang on -- you're clicking the Java binary using the finder? Do I understand you correctly?

That's not how Java works. It's a command line tool, not a graphical program. The help it's giving you is how you're supposed to call it. Understanding this is non-trivial. If you don't know how to use the terminal window and command line, you're going to be decidedly unhappy.

But here's something I just did from Terminal:

```
$ cat Hello.java
    public class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.printf("Hello, World!\n");
        }
    }
$ javac Hello.java
$ java Hello
Hello, World!
```

I use a $ as my command prompt, so each line that begins with a $ is a command in the terminal window. So I cat'd the program (printed it out) -- it's 5 simple lines. I then used javac to compile it. I then used the java command to run it.

Maybe I misunderstood what you're doing, though.

Comment: Thank you for a quick tutorial :) I am learning c for the sake of understanding how things working under the hood. So I know a bit of command line. I am now going to looking into javac the compiler, and also clojure which appears to be interesting to me x